# How do I tweak the increasing longest array sequence in C to equal or greater?

Tags: c

I am trying to code a function such that it gives me the longest consecutive increasing or equal sequence `n` within an array, for instance `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 }` would give `n = 5`.

However when I tried with `{ 7, 7 }`, my code returns `0`. I am not sure if I got the `if (array[i] >= array[i-1])` right.
Thank you in advance!

```
int longest(int array[], unsigned n) {
    //assign longest sequence
    int k = 0;
    int running_k = 1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (array[i] > array[i - 1]) {
            ++running_k;
        } else
        if (array[i] == array[i - 1]) {
            running_k = running_k + 1;
        } else {
            if (running_k > k) {
                k = running_k;
            }
            running_k = 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: anyone can help me with why {7,7} does not give an output of 2 even after i indicated an ith element is to be more than or equal to (i-1)th element?

Comment: Side note: you invoke undefined behaviour in the first iteration of your for loop. In the first iteration you access array[-1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- the argument `n`, the return value and the local variables should have type `size_t`.
- you should not read `array[i - 1]` when `i` is `0`, so the initial value of `i` should not be `0`, but `1`.
- the 2 tests inside the loop should be combined as:

  ```
    if (array[i] >= array[i - 1])
  ```
- you should check if `running_k > k` at the end of the loop, in case the longest running sequence is at the end of the array, which is the case for `{ 7, 7 }`.
- you should special case arrays of length `1` and `0`.

Here is a modified version:

```
size_t longest(const int *array, size_t n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;

    size_t k = 0;
    size_t running_k = 1;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= array[i - 1]) {
            ++running_k;
        } else {
            if (k < running_k) {
                k = running_k;
            }
            running_k = 1;
        }
    }
    if (k < running_k) {
        k = running_k;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return 0 if the longest sequence is of length 1.

```
int longest(int array[], unsigned n) {
    //assign longest sequence
    int k = 0;
    int running_k = 1;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        if (array[i] >= array[i-1] ){
            ++running_k;
        }
        else {
            if (running_k > k){
                k = running_k;
            }
            running_k = 1;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks! i edited that part, but i cannot figure out why for {7,7} the output is 2 , my objective is that ++k if the [i]>=[i-1]?

Comment: You are incrementing k if the array[i] is greater than or equal to array[i-1]. So, for {7,7}, the first 7 is greater than or equal to the 0th element in the array (which is also 7), so k is incremented. Then, the second 7 is greater than or equal to the first 7, so k is incremented again.

Comment: yes, but my output is not 2 , it gives me 1 on {7,7}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortened version of what you seek. I adjusted some of the types for consistency. `size_t` is a typedef for an unsigned int or unsigned long. You can likely change it back to `int` or `unsigned` as needed.

```
size_t longest(int* array, size_t n) {

   size_t length=1, best=1;

   if (n <= 1) {
      return n;
   }

   for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       length = (array[i] >= array[i-1]) ? (length + 1) : 1;      
       best = (length > best) ? length : best;
   }

   return best;
}
```